# Formatting in Numbers is driving me nuts

Tags: macos, numbers

I'm trying to do very basic cell formatting in Numbers. It is driving me crazy. I set a format and it simply ignores it, and then I format something else and the first one changes. What is the pattern here?

In this image I'm trying to format the cell B10 to look like B7. As you can see, B7 is a currency with 4 decimals. Well, on the right you can see that so is B10. So why isn't it formatting that way? Yes, I tried tabbing and clicking out and back in.

[image]

Comment: Weird. Can not repeat what you describe. Does it work with other currencies or if you choose "Number" as the data format rather than "Currency"? In any case, I suggest you restart Numbers and start working with a newly created Numbers file if possible.

Comment: It happens with all formats, I tried number, currency and automatic.